# The prominence of informative information on product pages

Tags: e-commerce, information-architecture, conversion-rate

So the question is: is it better to keep the main target of a product page such as selecting a size, colour etc and 'Buy Now' button in view and dropping other information such as returns policy, product description, delivery info, product reviews etc below/out the way of the main actionable/important elements?

So reason I ask a question which seems like an easy answer is mixing the two types of content together can over crowd the main objectives of a page and distract the user into viewing the full returns policy (on a separate page) but then on the other hand this type of information could install trust and back up the sale/action.

Example page: [www.costumecrowd.co.uk/1960s-cnd-costume~39438](http://www.costumecrowd.co.uk/1960s-cnd-costume~39438)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry what exactly is the question?

Comment: Sorry, basically should information such as returns policy, product description, delivery info, product reviews etc be moved into non-prominent areas (maybe below the fold) out the way of the main actions such as selecting a size, colour, buy now button?

On one hand mixing it all together may distract the user from the main CTA's.

And on the other, if the information is prominent it might actually install some trust in the user to do the CTA's.

Hope that makes it a little clearer, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should aim to create something prototypical to similar successful e-commerce sites. Take a look at the information displayed on their product pages and make notes or a data set on the elements displayed and where they are generally displayed. This doesn't mean that you have to make something boring -- instead you're looking to build an interface that people are already familiar with and don't have too learn.

Hope this helps!

- [This article](https://medium.com/design-ux/168074e9575) goes in-depth on this topic and others.